# Como manter um valor fixo dentro de uma função recursiva?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Eu gostaria de criar uma variável com o primeiro valor passado como parâmetro em uma função, mas toda vez que é feita uma chamada recursiva a variável recebe o valor do novo parâmetro passado. Por exemplo:

```
def fatorial(n)
    print(n)
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fatorial(n - 1)
```

No caso acima eu gostaria de imprimir apenas o valor passado como parâmetro na primeira vez. Tem como eu armazenar e imprimir apenas o primeiro valor passado? Se sim, como eu poderia implementar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é necessário armazenar o valor passado pela primeira vez. Ao invés disso, utilize uma variável de controle para decidir se você deve ou não imprimir o primeiro valor.

```python
def fatorial(n, imprima=False):
    if imprima:
      print(n)
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fatorial(n - 1)

print(fatorial(5, True))
```

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/IVUB/0).

Comment: Funcionou, mas tem alguma outra forma de armazenar em uma variável?

Comment: @RafaelLima você poderia armazenar o valor do parâmetro dentro da condição `if imprima`.

Comment: Como você quer somente o primeiro valor impresso, não vejo porque isso deve ser feito dentro da função.

Comment: Ao tentar armazenar e usar a variavel depois ainda está dando erro, mas a impressão do valor já resolve o meu problema.

Comment: Na verdade, o mais comum - e o que eu gosto - é deixar valor default do valor opcional ajustado para quem chama a função "de fora" - a função recursiva "sabe mais sobre si mesma" - (isso é, voce está pensndo no código dela quando escreve as chamadas a ela mesma), e é melhor que essas chamadas internas passem os parametros opcionais a mais.
Em resumo, mude o cabçalho para `def fatorial(n, imprima=True):` e a chamada interna para `fatorial(n - 1, imprima=False)` assim quem chama de fora não precisa se preocupar com o "imprima".

Comment: Dito tudo isso - é uma péssima ideia que uma função dessas 0- que é puramente numérica, imprima alguma coisa - a melhor prática mesmo é a função recursiva só retornar um valor - quem fizer a chamada de fora que imprima.

Comment: Se for um código real (em contraste com esse exemplo que é só didático)  em que o que vai se fazer com o valor final retornado é mais complicado que um simples `print` - ainda vale a pena manter a função recursiva sem um "special case` para quando é chamada de fora -e em vez disso criar uma outra função pequena, que só cuida de chamar a função recursiva, e imprimir ou gravar seus resultados.